# Excel VBA Type Mismatch 13 using ActiveWorkbook.Close

Tags: excel, vba, type-mismatch

I am running code in a primary workbook which opens a file; performs a data refresh; then I want to save the file.  Everything works until I try to save the workbook using `ActiveWorkbook.Close True`.  I get a "Runtime Error 13 Type Mismatch error".  After I click "End" on the debugging message...the file closes like I want it to.  I use `On Error Resume Next` preceding the line which didn't resolve the error either.

The workbook that I'm opening is the active workbook and is still open.  I've also tried to use `workbooks("").close true` with no luck.

BELOW IS MY CODE:

```
Option Explicit
Option Private Module


'CONSTANTS
Const sTEMP_PATH_NAME As Variant = "C:\Users\ta7464\Vivial\Budgets - Documents\2018 Forecast F8\AdminOnly\"
Const sTEMPLATE_WKBK As Variant = "BlankTemplate_V2.xlsm"



'VARIABLES


Public Sub DeployNewTemplates()

'1.  Turn off features
    'TurnOffFunctionality

'2.  Open the spreadsheet and activate Sheet2
    DeployTemplates

'3. Turn on features
    'TurnOnFunctionality

End Sub


Private Sub DeployTemplates()
    Dim sMainWkbk As Variant, sBlnkTemp As Variant, rDeptCds As Variant, DeptArr As Variant
    Dim i As Long, sDeptNo As String, sDeptNm As String, sWBName As Variant, sWBFullName As Variant
    Dim wbTemplate As Workbook, wbTarget As Workbook


    'Load array with list of valid department codes
    Set rDeptCds = shDepts.Range("A1").CurrentRegion
    DeptArr = rDeptCds.Value

    'Assign variable for the TemplateMgmtTool workbook
    sMainWkbk = Left(ThisWorkbook.Name, (InStrRev(ThisWorkbook.Name, ".", -1, vbTextCompare) - 1))
    sBlnkTemp = Left(sTEMPLATE_WKBK, (InStrRev(sTEMPLATE_WKBK, ".", -1, vbTextCompare) - 1))

    'Opens the blank template for population and saving

    Set wbTemplate = Workbooks.Open(Filename:=sTEMP_PATH_NAME & sTEMPLATE_WKBK)

    'Loop through all department numbers with actuals in the current year to customize and save a template for each
    For i = LBound(DeptArr) + 1 To UBound(DeptArr)
        sDeptNo = DeptArr(i, 1)
        sDeptNm = DeptArr(i, 2)
        sWBFullName = sDeptNo & "-" & sDeptNm & "_BT.xlsm"
        sWBName = sDeptNo & "-" & sDeptNm & "_BT"

        '1.  Save a copy of the blank template with proper naming convention
         Workbooks(sTEMPLATE_WKBK).Activate
         wbTemplate.SaveCopyAs PathName & sWBFullName
         Set wbTarget = Workbooks.Open(Filename:=PathName & sWBFullName)

        '2. Populate the shPL tab with the active department number

        Workbooks(sWBFullName).Worksheets("P&L").Range("C1").Value = DeptArr(i, 1)

        '3 Refresh the template connections and wait until complete before saving and closing
         wbTarget.Connections("Query - DeptNo").Refresh
         wbTarget.Connections("Query - CoRollUp").Refresh
         wbTarget.Connections("Query - Current Year Actuals").Refresh
         wbTarget.Connections("Query - DeptCode").Refresh
         wbTarget.Connections("Query - Oracle Headcount").Refresh
         wbTarget.Connections("Query - ButtsInSeats").Refresh


        '4 Save and close the newly created template
        On Error Resume Next
        ActiveWorkbook.Close True


    Next i

End Sub
```

Comment: The Active Workbook may not be the one you think. Since you have an object for the Workbook (`wbTemplate`), why not use that?

Comment: Runtime error 13 seems odd at that line of code, but you already have a reference to that workbook - does `wbTarget.Close True` (or `wbTemplate`, not sure what you intend to close) give you the same error?

Comment: That sure makes sense.  I thought for sure that would be the answer.  Still crashes with the same error message.

Comment: Is there a `Workbook_BeforeClose` or `BeforeSave` event handler in that workbook's `ThisWorkbook` module? If so, that could be the code throwing the error.

Comment: Wow Mathieu.  That was the answer.  Out of curiosity...why would that cause an issue?  Thanks again for your help.